# Where can I find PDFMiner API definitions?

Tags: python, pdfminer

Is there a good `API` definition for the `Python PDFMiner package`?

For example I can see from the source code that LTText contains `x0, y0, x1, y1` and some text and there is a `get_text()` method that returns the text - but is the intention to just access x0... directly?

In which case why wrap the text using _text and `get_text()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project isn't heavily documented, so you'll have to figure it out on your own. There is, however, [some documentation](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/programming.html) in the form of basic explanations of the main classes and structure.

For your specific question, `LTText` functions like an abstract base class. Some objects that inherit from `LTText` override the `get_text` method and do something more complicated, like [`LTTextContainer`](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L328-L336):

```
class LTTextContainer(LTExpandableContainer, LTText):
    def __init__(self):
        LTText.__init__(self)
        LTExpandableContainer.__init__(self)
        return

    def get_text(self):
        return ''.join(obj.get_text() for obj in self if isinstance(obj, LTText))
```

Usually getter and setter methods wrap functionality that may be useful to override in subclasses or update state that depends on the input. For example, [`LTComponent.set_bbox`](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L101-L110) updates six other attributes besides `self.bbox`.